# c++ system command

Tags: c++, system-calls

I have written a sample c++ program...here i am using system command to call python program with an argument...

```
system("python /home/rpms/a3/dsp/noise_rem_python.py /home/rpms/a3/dsp/files/p1f%d.txt",tid);

/home/rpms/a3/dsp/noise_rem_python.py is a program name
```

`/home/rpms/a3/dsp/files/p1f%d.txt` is a parameter for this program.

but I am getting error as:

> "/usr/include/stdlib.h: In function ‘void* writefile(void*)’:
>   /usr/include/stdlib.h:712: error: too many arguments to function ‘int system(const char*)’
>   writefile.cpp:29: error: at this point in file"

Comment: C++ isn't magic. It won't just format a string for you out if thin air.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it this way:

```
char command[200];    // 200 is just an example value that can hold the whole string
sprintf(command, "python /home/rpms/a3/dsp/noise_rem_python.py /home/rpms/a3/dsp/files/p1f%d.txt", tid);
system(command);
```

if you want to do it in the same style.

Answer (score 1):

Say this:

```
#include <string>

system(("python /home/rpms/a3/dsp/noise_rem_python.py /home/rpms/a3/dsp/files/p1f" + std::to_string(tid) + ".txt").c_str());
```

Comment: You're missing an opening `(` around the string expression.

Comment: @JamesKanze: thanks, fixed! I had a `std::string` around the first part originally, but that's actually not needed.

Comment: `std::to_string()` is C++11 only. We don't know if the OP can use it.

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(tid)` is an alternative if C++11 is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

look at the end of the arguments you are passing in to the function

... ,tid);

if you are trying to format a string? Do it before you use it as an argument.